# could not start a new session on selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, port, gecko

I'm trying to open firefox browser using selenium java code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.port","4444");
```

The Selenium server is up and running. I tried to change the selenium server port using command prompt and set the port in code, but neither of them works.

```
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
System info: host: 'W0045395', ip: '10.17.208.124', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:670)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:220)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
    at newpackage.Gmail_Login.main(Gmail_Login.java:18)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:6544 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
System info: host: 'W0045395', ip: '10.17.208.124', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:649)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:6544 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    ... 22 more
```

In the error message, "Connect to localhost:6544" it tried to connect to a different localhost everytime. Can anyone see where the problem is?

The versions I'm using are:

- firefox 48.0
- selenium 3.0.0 beta 2
- windows 7 32 bits
- geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32

Also my geckodriver executable isn't running, it says VCRUNTIME140.dill is missing and I should reinstall to fix the problem. But after I reinstalled it, same thing happened.

---

updates

Thanks for @Saurabh's suggestion, I downgraded my selenium to 2.53.1. The browser is opening now, but nothing shows up. And I got another error

```
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
ateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":"chrome://web2pdfextension/skin/C_AdobeLogo_48x48.png","icon64URL":"chrome://web2pdfextension/skin/C_AdobeLogo_64x64.png","defaultLocale":{"name":"Adobe Acrobat DC - Create PDF","description":"Converts a web page to PDF","creator":"Adobe Systems Incorporated","homepageURL":"http://www.adobe.com/"},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":true,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat\\Browser\\WCFirefoxExtn","installDate":1463491629403,"updateDate":1463491629403,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"skinnable":false,"size":345393,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"4.0","maxVersion":"46.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
1471356838157   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471356838157   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1471356838157   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1471356838158   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1471356838161   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1471356838162   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1471356838162   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1471356838162   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
1471356838163   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1471356838164   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.4.3
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1471356838182   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1471356838188   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1471356839788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1471356839788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1471356839788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1471356840362   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1471356840362   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1471356840362   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1471356840374   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1471356840374   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471356840377   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1471356840413   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471356840413   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1471356840413   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471356840421   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471356840440   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471356840460   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1471356840495   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:129)
    at newpackage.Gmail_Login.main(Gmail_Login.java:25)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
ateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":"chrome://web2pdfextension/skin/C_AdobeLogo_48x48.png","icon64URL":"chrome://web2pdfextension/skin/C_AdobeLogo_64x64.png","defaultLocale":{"name":"Adobe Acrobat DC - Create PDF","description":"Converts a web page to PDF","creator":"Adobe Systems Incorporated","homepageURL":"http://www.adobe.com/"},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":true,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat\\Browser\\WCFirefoxExtn","installDate":1463491629403,"updateDate":1463491629403,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"skinnable":false,"size":345393,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"4.0","maxVersion":"46.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
1471356838157   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471356838157   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1471356838157   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1471356838158   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1471356838161   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1471356838162   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1471356838162   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1471356838162   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
1471356838163   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1471356838164   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.4.3
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1471356838182   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1471356838188   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1471356839788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1471356839788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1471356839788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1471356840362   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1471356840362   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1471356840362   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1471356840374   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1471356840374   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471356840377   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1471356840413   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471356840413   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1471356840413   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471356840421   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471356840440   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471356840460   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1471356840495   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:09'
System info: host: 'W0045395', ip: '10.17.208.124', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:129)
    at newpackage.Gmail_Login.main(Gmail_Login.java:25)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
ateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":"chrome://web2pdfextension/skin/C_AdobeLogo_48x48.png","icon64URL":"chrome://web2pdfextension/skin/C_AdobeLogo_64x64.png","defaultLocale":{"name":"Adobe Acrobat DC - Create PDF","description":"Converts a web page to PDF","creator":"Adobe Systems Incorporated","homepageURL":"http://www.adobe.com/"},"visible":true,"active":false,"userDisabled":true,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Acrobat DC\\Acrobat\\Browser\\WCFirefoxExtn","installDate":1463491629403,"updateDate":1463491629403,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"skinnable":false,"size":345393,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"4.0","maxVersion":"46.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":2,"seen":true}
1471356838157   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471356838157   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1471356838157   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1471356838158   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1471356838161   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1471356838162   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.0
1471356838162   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1471356838162   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.4
1471356838163   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1471356838164   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.4.3
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1471356838181   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1471356838182   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1471356838187   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1471356838188   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1471356839788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1471356839788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1471356839788   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1471356840362   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1471356840362   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
1471356840362   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1471356840374   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1471356840374   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1471356840377   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1471356840413   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471356840413   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1471356840413   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1471356840421   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471356840440   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1471356840460   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1471356840495   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: do you have firefox installed on your machine?

Comment: why do you want to use gecko driver? for launching firefox you should be able to import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

Comment: @AllIsWell Yes, I have firefox installed. I think I was this error "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/jgraham/wires. The latest version can be downloaded from ....". So I used gecko instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `DesiredCapabilities` with `marionette` capability to `true` into `FirefoxDriver` as well as below :-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");

//Now you can Initialize marionette driver to launch firefox
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

**Edited** : If unfortunately above does not work, I would suggest you to **downgrade your firefox to 45 or less** and use `FirefoxDriver` as below :-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh, thank you for your response. I tried the above code and also set up the Marionette executable. But it still gives me the same error.

Comment: That would finally open the browser! but it's not showing anything on the browser. and it gives me "org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms" error

Comment: Ok try as : `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");
//Now you can Initialize marionette driver to launch firefox
WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver();` and let me know..

Comment: hmm.the code before would open the browser. but now it just gave me the previous error "org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException"

Comment: Please let me know what is your installed firefox binary location??? Is it installed in default location or other location??

Comment: C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox

Comment: and gecko driver is installed in this folder

Comment: Please uninstall your firefox and then fresh install again. And put geckodriver to some different location instead of firefox default installed location and use this location to `System.setProperty` and run your code again and let me know

Comment: its the same error. I'm trying to downgrade FF but that doesn't seem like working

Comment: Ah so weird why is it not working in your case... you can downgrade it to 45 or less and use as normal Firefox driver. Leave geckodriver...

Comment: I downgraded to 44 and it works now! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure all jar files added, including from /lib folder too the following snippet code would open the browser with added http link. By the way, I used win7 64bit, so keep eyes on the geckodrive path.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Documents\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

try {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```